# Clipping image within SVG

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I am making a 3D button that has a cutout to show a picture. The background image somehow shows much smaller than the actual circle.

Here are the lines in question (below is the CodePen link):

```
    <g>
        <defs>
            <pattern id="image" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" height="78" width="78">
                <image
                    xlink:href="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mighty355/images/b/b1/025Pikachu_XY_anime_3.png/">
                </image>
            </pattern>
        </defs>
        <circle cx="133.6" cy="133.7" r="78.7" fill="url(#image)" />
    </g>
```

The entire file is this:
https://codepen.io/lemmerelassal/pen/GRjrNwe

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <g>
        <image xlink:href="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mighty355/images/b/b1/025Pikachu_XY_anime_3.png/"
            style="clip-path: circle(30% at 50% 50%); width: 267px; height: 267px ;">
        </image>
    </g>
```

works